# Why we can use partial derivatives to tell if a force is conservative?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, work, potential-energy, conservative-field

Let us, initially, analysis only a two dimension situation. Assume that $F(x,y)$ is a force dependent on the particle position (give by $x,y$) is proposed that if

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial x}}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial y}}{\partial x}
\end{equation}

where $F_x$ is the component of the force in $x$ axis and $F_y$ is the component of the force in $y$ axis.

> The proposition is: If the equation above is true to the force $F$ then this force is [conservative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force) and we can write a potential function associated with this force.

Is this proposition true?

Remembering that the equation above is the same of say:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \frac{\partial (-U)}{\partial x}}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial \frac{\partial (-U)}{\partial y}}{\partial x}
\end{equation}

implying for example that the work done by this force in any path does not depend on the path only in the initial and final positions..

in this lecture one can see better what is asked: http://youtu.be/R74EhX8O0Nw?t=1h1m49s

Comment: Hint: $\nabla \times \vec{F}=0$ for conservative forces

Comment: Hi Yassin and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic). Having said this, TheGhostOfPerdition has given you a biiiiiiiiig hint :-)

Comment: I think it is not a homework, sorry, but why this would be a homework? Is like to say that a question like why f=ma is true or in what conditions the equation holds is homework, you agree with me that this doesn't a homework right?